# Wordpress Meta Slider Pro and NextGEN Gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have installed MetaSlider Pro and Next GEN Gallery together for wordpress. But there is a conflict, and Next GEN Gallery fails to load at all, just a blury icon shows. WHen i turn off Meta Slider pro Next GEN Gallery works. Any one know how I could debug this conflict.

**EDIT:** I have found that the conflict only occurs when you use the Post Feed Slide (in MetaSlider Pro) with Next GEN Gallery, all other sliders appear to work ok with Next GEN gallery. So it must be something conflicting between that post slider and Next GEN. All Next GEN shows is.

```
<img class="ngg_displayed_gallery mceItem" width="640" height="363" alt="" src="http://infinite.somewhere.net/index.php/nextgen-attach_to_post/preview/id--380">
```

**EDIT 2: 21/07/2014**

After doing some investigation I found that the file module.attach_to_post.php in NextGEN gallery had a function called substitute_placeholder_imgs that was supposed to fire when content was processed, but it appears to be overridden by Meta Slider Pro's post content. i.e. the following line

```
add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'substitute_placeholder_imgs'), PHP_INT_MAX, 1);
```

Is not actually firing on the main content, but it does fire and replace the Meta Slider content posts. The following is the page content:

```
<div class="content-pad">
<div class="hideifmobile">[metaslider id=105]</div>
<div class="hideifweb">[metaslider id=276]</div>
</div>
<img class="ngg_displayed_gallery mceItem" src="http://infinite.cybernamixqld.net/index.php/nextgen-attach_to_post/preview/id--380" alt="" width="640" height="363" />
```

After replacement the following occurs.

```
<div class="content-pad">
<div class="hideifmobile">SUCCESSFULLY REPLACED WITH SLIDER</div>
<div class="hideifweb">SUCCESSFULLY REPLACED WITH SLIDER</div>
</div>
<img class="ngg_displayed_gallery mceItem" src="http://infinite.cybernamixqld.net/index.php/nextgen-attach_to_post/preview/id--380" alt="" width="640" height="363" />
```

The Next GEN gallery image is not replaced with the gallery.

I also found out that the regular expression did not appear to be working properly, and had to change it to deal with multiple galleries on the same page. This change could be an error (On my part) so don't do it if every thing is working fine for you.

```
//old preg_match_all("#<img.*http(s)?://({$preview_url}|{$alt_preview_url})/id--(\\d+).*\\/>#mi", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)

        if (preg_match_all("#<img[^>]*http(s)?://({$preview_url}|{$alt_preview_url})/id--(\\d+)[^>]*>#mi", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
```

I still have not solved this problem. Still looking for why the main page content is not being parsed by 'the_content' call, all post in the slider are being parsed however. Any ideas anybody?????

Comment: `Next GEN Gallery fails` could be anything, unless you're waiting for magicians we can't guess the problem if you doesn't describe it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a way to temporarily fix this problem. It is not the best way but it does work.

Alter your page/post templates in your theme in the following way:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php  ob_start(); the_content(); $data = ob_get_clean(); echo fixsliderbug($data);  ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then add the following function into your theme.

```
function fixsliderbug($data){
    if (preg_match_all("#<img[^>]*http(s)?://([^>]*)/id--(\\d+)[^>]*>#mi", $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) { 

        foreach ($matches as $match) {
                $out = apply_filters('the_content',$match[0]);
                $data = str_replace($match[0], $out, $data);
        }

   }


    return  $data;
}
```

What this does is to find any Next GEN sliders that were missed in the parsing of the content, and parse them at run time. I am sure there are better solutions out there but if you need a quick and dirty way to get your site running try the above.